# JasperReports Server: How to fix error if no data available in report?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, visualize

I have created a report in Jaspersoft Studio with `Domain as Datasource` and some parameters `(fromDate and toDate)` to make my report dynamic based on DATE criteria and published in JasperReports Server which works fine - If data is there report loads based on date parameters and If data not available shows *"No data found on selected criteria"*.

But while loading the report in my application using `visualize.js`, If data is there report loads based on the selected date parameters, But If data not there, the page keep on loading with an error in console "***Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined    - in visualize.js:2028***"

For More Information

I have already selected "`No-data section`" for "`When no data`" option in report properties and edited `nodata field with my static message`, which loads fine in Jasperserver but not in my application through visualize js.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid errors by setting in JasperSoftStudio report property "When no data type"= "All sections No Detail"

Comment: I have already tried with this ("When no data type"= "All sections No Detail") option. But no changes the page keeps loading without any message and i can find the same error in console